# Sorting a file manager array by file type

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, file-manager

I am creating a file manager for my users, it's pretty basic right now and lists every folder and file within their directory.

```
<?PHP
  function getFileList($dir)
  {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open pointer to directory and read list of files
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
      if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry/",
          "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => 0,
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry",
          "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      }
    }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
  }
?>
```

It then echos this information in to a responsive table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Select</th>
                                            <th>Filename</th>
                                            <th>Type</th>
                                            <th>Last Modified</th>
                                            <th>Size</th>
                                            <th>Actions</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <?
 $dirlist = getFileList("../test/".$ref."");
  // output file list in HTML TABLE format
  foreach($dirlist as $file) {
      $files = $file['name'];
      $tmp = explode('../test/'.$ref.'/', $files);
      $filename = end($tmp);
      $filenames = rtrim($filename, '/');
  ?>
                                        <tr class="odd gradeX">           
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test"></td>
                                            <td><a href="<? if($file['type'] == 'dir'){ echo 'user_filemanager.php?ref='.$ref.'/'.$filenames.''; } else { echo 'http://mysite.co.uk/test/'.$ref.'/'.$filenames.''; } ?>"><? echo $filenames; ?></a></td>
                                            <td><? echo $file['type']; ?></td>
                                            <td class="center"><? echo date('r', $file['lastmod']) ?></td>
                                            <td class="center"><? echo $file['size']; ?></td>
                                            <td class="center">X</td>
                                        </tr>
  <?
  }
  ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

The issue I have is it outputs the data at random. I would like for it to display all Directories FIRST. Before listing files. So all directories are on top. Is this possible? Directories currently display as `dir` from `$file['type'];`

Comment: So sort result array before output. With `usort` for example.

Comment: I've looked it up but not found an example of how I would use it for this type of thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example of `usort` in your case is:

```
function getFileList($dir)
{
    // code here

    // sort by `type` key:
    usort($retval, function($a, $b) { return $a['type'] == 'dir'? -1 : 1; });

    return $retval;
}
```